# How to insert Data into database using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an `Asp.net` *web application*. I have to use `javascript` to insert data on the same local machine, where I'm already using a `3-tier` architecture and `Stored procedures`.

My question is:

Is there a way to insert data starting from `javascript` ?
please explain how this can be done ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to use AJAX? GIYF

Comment: @Aristos I have SQL Server 2005 and I am using my own local PC and hence want to store data into my database with help of javascript

Comment: No @Happy I am not ...

Comment: @Aristos Actually We have a web application product, like just a kind of ERP. Now we have to upgrade this. So we want to use Javascript/Jquery as much as possible in place of C# code .SO I want to try this ...

Comment: You cannot insert into database from javascript. You need to use ADO.Net or Entity Framework to access the database.  Send you data via JSON or xml or query parameters to a web handler or a callback method and perform your desired operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you'll have to traverse all your tiers. You may use AJAX on the client and have an ASMX on the receiving end which actually inserts the data. Pay attention to authentication and security, attackers might send an HTTP request to the ASMX directly.

Alternatively, you'll have to post back your data through a form. Javascript does not contribute much here, in my opinion.

Now that I've read your later comments I see that it's all on your local machine.

Read about HTML5 and local storage, maybe this is what you need:

http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax and webmethod you can able to insert the data.

[Click here](http://deebujacob.blogspot.in/2012/01/aspnet-ajax-web-method-call-using.html) to know more

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this but my suggestion is:

In client side you can use:

- JQuery methods to submit your data ($.post or $.ajax) [see this link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

In server side you can use:

- web services that send/receive json requests [see this tutorial](http://wcftutorial.net/How_To_JSON_Using_WCF.aspx)

Remeber that with javascript the preferable way to send and receive data is using JSON data format.